# Android In-App Billing goes to Google Play after successful purchase

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented the Android In-App Billing successfully in my app. And after Google issued update to Google Play, the in-app billing takes me to the Google Play application on successful purchase.

Why is this happening? Where is the error? Is there something I have missed out?